# What is the difference between `temp_string.as_str()` and `&temp_string`?

Tags: rust

This code triggers a compiler error:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = "FOO";
    let s_lower = s.to_lowercase().as_str();

    println!("{}", s_lower);    
}
```

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:3:19
  |
3 |     let s_lower = s.to_lowercase().as_str();
  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |                   |
  |                   creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
4 |
5 |     println!("{}", s_lower);    
  |                    ------- borrow later used here
```

However, this code does not:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "FOO";
    let s_lower = &s.to_lowercase();

    println!("{}", s_lower);    
}
```

Why? Is it because `&temp_string` is a `&String` which is different from `&str`? If so, how?

Comment: The reason is that `let x = &…;` is ["special"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/error-index.html#E0716): "Temporaries are not always dropped at the end of the enclosing statement. […]"

Answer (score 1):

Several links from @kmdreko & @sudo are helpful.

I understand why `s.to_lowercase().to_str()` does not compile but wondered why `&s.to_lowercase()` does not have the same problem.
This is called [**Temporary lifetime extension**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/reference/destructors.html#temporary-lifetime-extension), the doc says:

*The temporary scopes for expressions in let statements are sometimes extended to the scope of the block containing the let statement. This is done when the usual temporary scope would be too small, based on certain syntactic rules. For example:*

```rust
let x = &mut 0;
// Usually a temporary would be dropped by now, but the temporary for `0` lives
// to the end of the block.
println!("{}", x);
```

I find this special rule a bit arbitrary. Here's a [related discussion](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-understand-temporary-lifetime-extension-correctly/70503) on why it does not apply to `temp.as_bytes()` which I resonate.

Surprisingly [there's a RFC](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0066-better-temporary-lifetimes.html) which seemed to want to make this more regular, but somehow is not applicable here.

[This article](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/01/09/rvalue-lifetimes-in-rust/#the-problem) explains why Temporary Lifetime Extension is desired in some cases.

I found this [older rust references](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/rust-1.36.0-docs-html/reference/expressions.html#temporary-lifetimes) helpful with understanding temporary values as well, with a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are a two points to make here.

1. Yes, `&String` and `&str` are different types. The former is a reference to a dynamic heap string type, the latter is a string slice which is a reference to part of a string. I recommend reviewing this [chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html) of the Rust book on slices.
2. The lifetime of the temporary is the real culprit as the error message indicates.

In the first example, the return type of `to_lowercase()` is `String` - it is returning a `String` that will be owned by the caller. However we are not binding this return value to a variable - we're attempting to call `as_str()` first and then binding the result of that to `s_lower`. `as_str()` can't be chained with `to_lowercase()` without first binding the result because it needs to take a reference to the calling `String`, which can't be done on a temporary. This is problematic because the `String` returned by `to_lowercase()` ends up being dropped (deallocated and unusable) **before** `as_str()` is called as the compiler realizes it can't be used.

To make it clearer, he first example is sort of equivalent to:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "FOO";
    // temporary scope
    {
        let temporary = s.to_lowercase();
    }
    let s_lower = temporary.as_str();
}
```

based on the temporary value [rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#temporaries) The lifetime of the temporary is hopefully clearer this way. To fix the first example you would have to do:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "FOO";
    let s_lower = &s.to_lowercase();
    let s_lower_slice = s_lower.as_str();
    println!("{s_lower_slice}");
}
```

which is further explained in the answer @kmdreko linked [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71230066/temp-string-as-str-and-temp-string/71232326#comment125909622_71230066)